# Unable to Provide the YAML config file for Clang Taint Analysis clang-tidy and scan-build

Tags: clang, clang-tidy, taint

I came accross this clang article for taint analysis:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/analyzer/user-docs/TaintAnalysisConfiguration.html#clangsa-taint-configuration-example

In the article, it is mentioned that source and sink can be specified using a YAML file. Any idea how this YAML file can be provided to either scan-build or clang-tidy commands? I don't see a clear option that can be used with scan-build to provide this file. And, for clang-tidy, when I write that content in the .clang-tidy file, clang exists with error saying that it can't identify the 'Propagation' key.

For clang-tidy which comes with clang-17 on ubuntu 22.04 I tried

```
clang-tidy -checks alpha.security.taint.TaintPropagation ../llvmTaintAnalysis.c
```

It doesn't report any errors, but it doesn't show the analysis result since, I am not able to define the source/sink of the taint.

Here is the code that I need to test, the source is the argument of the function update_len_value, and the sink is the argument of the function update_len_here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 4

struct s_len_t {
  unsigned int *plen;
};

struct s_s_len_t {
  struct s_len_t *s_len;
};

void update_len_here(unsigned int *plen4)
{
  *plen4 = 1000;
}

void intermediate3(unsigned int *plen3)
{
  update_len_here(plen3);
}

void intermediate2(unsigned int *plen2)
{
  intermediate3(plen2);
}

void intermediate1(struct s_len_t *s_len)
{
  intermediate2(s_len->plen);
}

void update_len_value(struct s_s_len_t *s_s_len)
{
  intermediate1(s_s_len->s_len);
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int var = 5;

  struct s_len_t s_len;
  struct s_s_len_t s_s_len = {.s_len = &s_len};
  struct s_s_len_t *p_s_s_len = &s_s_len;
  p_s_s_len->s_len->plen = &var;

  update_len_value(p_s_s_len);

  char srcArray[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
  char destArray[MAX_SIZE] = {0};

  for (int i = 0; i < *p_s_s_len->s_len->plen; i++) {
      destArray[i] = srcArray[i];
  }

  return destArray[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

To specify (say) `taint-config.yaml` as the taint configuration file to
`scan-build`, add these arguments:

```
-analyzer-config alpha.security.taint.TaintPropagation:Config=taint-config.yaml
```

### Complete example

Here is the test input file, modified a little (look for `**ADDED**` and
`**CHANGED**`, one each, plus a few added comments):

```
// test.c
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76547817/unable-to-provide-the-yaml-config-file-for-clang-taint-analysis-clang-tidy-and-s

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 4

struct s_len_t {
  unsigned int *plen;
};

struct s_s_len_t {
  struct s_len_t *s_len;
};

// The argument to this function is a taint sink, and is configured as
// such in 'taint-config.yaml'.
void update_len_here(unsigned int *plen4)
{
  *plen4 = 1000;
}

void intermediate3(unsigned int *plen3)
{
  update_len_here(plen3);
}

void intermediate2(unsigned int *plen2)
{
  intermediate3(plen2);
}

void intermediate1(struct s_len_t *s_len)
{
  intermediate2(s_len->plen);
}

// The argument to this function is meant to be a taint source.  But
// that's not really how sources work since they arise from call sites.
void update_len_value(struct s_s_len_t *s_s_len)
{
  intermediate1(s_s_len->s_len);
}

// So, instead, in 'taint-config.yaml', we will configure this function
// as a source, and call it in 'main()' in order to build the argument
// to 'update_len_value'.
unsigned int *get_tainted_ptr(); // **ADDED**

int main()
{
  unsigned int var = 5;

  struct s_len_t s_len;
  struct s_s_len_t s_s_len = {.s_len = &s_len};
  struct s_s_len_t *p_s_s_len = &s_s_len;
  p_s_s_len->s_len->plen = get_tainted_ptr(); // **CHANGED** (was '&var')

  update_len_value(p_s_s_len);

  char srcArray[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
  char destArray[MAX_SIZE] = {0};

  for (int i = 0; i < *p_s_s_len->s_len->plen; i++) {
      destArray[i] = srcArray[i];
  }

  return destArray[0];
}
```

Configuration file:

```
# taint-config.yaml
# Configuration file for TaintPropagation checker.

Propagations:
  # The return value of 'get_tainted_ptr' is a taint source.
  - Name: get_tainted_ptr
    DstArgs: [-1]

Sinks:
  # The first argument of 'update_len_here' is a taint sink.
  - Name: update_len_here
    Args: [0]

# EOF
```

Command and output:

```
$ scan-build -enable-checker alpha.security.taint.TaintPropagation \
    -analyzer-config alpha.security.taint.TaintPropagation:Config=taint-config.yaml \
    gcc -c test.c
scan-build: Using '/home/scott/opt/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin/clang-14' for static analysis
test.c:25:3: warning: Untrusted data is passed to a user-defined sink [alpha.security.taint.TaintPropagation]
  update_len_here(plen3);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
scan-build: Analysis run complete.
scan-build: 1 bug found.
scan-build: Run 'scan-view /tmp/scan-build-2023-06-25-034948-65899-1' to examine bug reports.
```

Observe that the console output only reports the place that tainted data
reaches the sink.

To see the full data flow path, run the `scan-view` command shown in
that output.  That will open a web browser to show more details.  In the
web browser, navigating to the finding will show the code interspersed
with taint flow path information like this:

[image: Screenshot of web browser showing taint flow]

### What about `clang-tidy`?

I was unable to get the taint checkers to report anything when using
`clang-tidy`.  I suspect that is because they are part of the
[Cross Translation Unit](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/analyzer/user-docs/CrossTranslationUnit.html)
analysis system, and either `clang-tidy` cannot do CTU or it requires
something more complicated than just running it in the usual way.
(The linked documentation page does not explain how to do CTU with
either `clang-tidy` or `scan-build`.)

Comment: Thanks Scott McPeak for your time, detailed answer, and for providing the way how the YAML file can be given to scan-build command. 

However, I ran the same example you provided with clang 17, but I don't get the same results like yours. 

I am still investigating why, but if you have any idea what could be the problem, please let me know.

Comment: @F1o0T There is no clang+llvm 17 at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases .  The most recent there is 16.0.6.  There is also no clang-17 at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clang&searchon=names&suite=jammy&section=all .  The latest there is clang-15.  So I don't know how to get the version you are using.